# Where can I hide Rico Delgado's body after killing him as the tattooist?

Tags: hitman-2

In the Three-Headed Serpent mission, one of the targets, Rico Delgado, can be killed by disguising yourself as P-Power, starting work on Rico's tattoo, then stabbing him after all potential witnesses have left Rico's office.

After this, however, I'm left with a body in a room with no closets, a guard waiting outside the door, and more guards patrolling outside should I want to leave from the balcony. Even the adjacent bathroom gets searched when the guard notices Rico has vanished. Is it possible to hide Rico's body after killing him in his office, or is this always going to break my Silent Assassin rating?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I did for this mission was to save Rico Delgado for last, as he has an escape route very nearby. After killing Rico, I deposited his body out of view of the door where guard comes in, then stealth knocked out the guard who came to check in. I then left his body on top of Rico's body, took the car key from Rico and the guard's uniform, then jumped off the balcony and made a break for the garage to escape.

There is also a closet in his wife's dressing room which you can use to dump his body.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to complete the tattoo without killing him. He checks your work in the mirror, then when he goes to get a drink knock him out and throw him off the balcony. It gets marked as an accidental death and won't wreck your silent assassin status. Then just stroll out of there.

Comment: Isn't there a guard that walks in around then? It might be hard to sneak past him.